# How to define mdf,ldf files default location path in SQL script

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

I want to give the script below to my client for installing a new database.
How can i rewrite this part of script to reflect their specific data and log file locations:

```
USE [master]
GO
/****** Object:  Database [PhoneBook]    Script Date: 2016/1/13 11:02:34 AM ******/
CREATE DATABASE [PhoneBook]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'PhoneBook', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\PhoneBook.mdf' , SIZE = 5120KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'PhoneBook_log', FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL12.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\PhoneBook_log.ldf' , SIZE = 2048KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)
GO
```

My client's windows drive is not c.
Can i change these paths to reflect their sql installation path?
How can i tell this script find the right location?

Comment: what do you mean by **Can i change these absolute path s**

Comment: mean what is the replacement of this %win% in T-SQL or something like that or is there any command to give Data folder path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
USE [master]
GO

DECLARE @mdfPath NVARCHAR(max), @ldfPath NVARCHAR(max) , @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX), @instName NVARCHAR(max) = 'PhoneBook'


SELECT @mdfPath = SUBSTRING(physical_name, 1,CHARINDEX(N'master.mdf',LOWER(physical_name)) - 1)+@instName+N'.mdf'
       ,@ldfPath = SUBSTRING(physical_name, 1,CHARINDEX(N'master.mdf',LOWER(physical_name)) - 1)+@instName+N'.ldf'
FROM master.sys.master_files
WHERE database_id = 1 AND FILE_ID = 1


SELECT @SQL =
'CREATE DATABASE [PhoneBook]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N'''+@instName+''', FILENAME = N'''+@mdfPath+''' , SIZE = 5120KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N'''+@instName+'_log'', FILENAME = N'''+@ldfPath+''' , SIZE = 2048KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%)'

PRINT(@SQL)
EXECUTE(@SQL)

GO
```

Comment: obviously I would say go for mine ;)

Comment: Go for mine. I had an explanation of what I did :)

Answer (score 3):

For SQL Server 2012 and above, you can use these Server properties as found [here](http://sqlserverzest.com/2013/05/23/how-to-get-the-default-database-data-file-and-and-data-file-location-using-t-sql-query/) as long as their default data and log file directories are set at the server level. You could do something like this using dynamic sql:

```
USE [master]
GO

DECLARE @defaultDataPath NVARCHAR(MAX) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultDataPath'))
DECLARE @defaultLogPath NVARCHAR(MAX) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), SERVERPROPERTY('InstanceDefaultLogPath'))
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 

'CREATE DATABASE [PhoneBook]
 CONTAINMENT = NONE
 ON  PRIMARY 
( NAME = N''PhoneBook'', FILENAME = N''' + @defaultDataPath + 'PhoneBook.mdf'' , SIZE = 5120KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )
 LOG ON 
( NAME = N''PhoneBook_log'', FILENAME = N''' + @defaultLogPath + 'PhoneBook_log.ldf'' , SIZE = 2048KB , MAXSIZE = 2048GB , FILEGROWTH = 10%) '

PRINT @sql
EXEC (@sql)
```

Comment: Go for mine. I had an explanation of what I did :)